MS Word VBA - InlineShapes.AddPicture Image Orientation and Height/Width mismatch
I have a VBA script which takes a folder of images, imported through inlineshapes.addpicture, compares the height/width of the photo then rotates the page for that image to match the photos orientation.
For a large portion of photos this code works fine.
However, for some photos, the image will import to the doc as portrait but the height/width values would suggest it is landscape and set the page to landscape. This could also happen the other way round (i.e. landscape as portrait)
This makes no sense as I can see the image is in the portrait orientation in the document but when checking size/position sure enough the values are showing as landscape.
Does anyone know why this would be and how I could check the value of height/width based on how it is showing in the document?
It's like word is importing as a rotated photo?

Are you joking? How do you imagine that somebody can help you without seeing the code you use?

What do you get when you check the rotation angle of the picture?

@funthomas Thanks for the helpful comment. Yes I've kept having a crack at this and can see it's showing as rotated 90°.

I've just been trialling inlineshape.converttoshape and then the .rotation function but I have found it to break other parts of the application.

Width and height of a picture (shape or inline shape) reflect the actual size of the shape. Those values don't change if the shape is rotated. So if width > height, you have a landscape image, however, if you rotate is 90 degrees, it looks as if it is an portrait image.
I am not sure what you want to do now:
Either you want to rotate the image back to 0 degrees. After that, the logic that sets the page orientation is correct.
Or you simply want to check if an image is rotated. For an image that is rotated by 90 or 270 degrees, you need to "exchange" width and height value: You will need landscape orientation if height > width.
Now (to my knowledge), Microsoft has not exposed the rotation property of an inline shape in VBA. The only way to rotate a shape (or query its rotation), is to convert it to a shape. If the document layout or your following code depends on having inline shapes, you can immediately convert it back.
Maybe the following routines can help you
Function getImageRotation(ish As InlineShape) As Double
    Dim sh As Shape
    Set sh = ish.ConvertToShape
    getImageRotation = sh.rotation
    sh.ConvertToInlineShape
End Function

Sub rotateImage(ish As InlineShape, Optional rotation As Double = 0)
     Dim sh As Shape
     Set sh = ish.ConvertToShape
     sh.rotation = rotation
     sh.ConvertToInlineShape
End Sub

Function isPortrait(ish As InlineShape) As Boolean
    Dim angle As Double
    angle = getImageRotation(ish) Mod 180
    
    If angle > 45 And angle < 135 Then
        isPortrait = ish.Width > ish.Height
    Else
        isPortrait = ish.Width < ish.Height
    End If
End Function

Function isLandscape(ish As InlineShape) As Boolean
    isLandscape = not isPortrait(ish)
End Function

